# Method in Java for creating an array with arbitrary number of dimensions

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible in Java to create a method that return an array with the number of dimensions passed by parameter?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static Object buildMultiDimensionalArray(int numDimensions) {

    if (numDimensions==1) {
        return new int[1];
    }
    if (numDimensions==2) {
        return new int[2][2];
    }
    if (numDimensions==3) {
        return new int[3][3][3];
    }
    if (numDimensions==4) {
        return new int[4][4][4][4];
    }
    if (numDimensions==5) {
        return new int[5][5][5][5][5];
    }
    if (numDimensions==6) {
        return new int[6][6][6][6][6][6];
    }
    // and so on...
    return null;
}
```

But this works only for dimensions up to 6.

Is it possible to make this method work for any number of dimensions?

Comment: So the number of elements in each dimension should always be equal to the number of dimensions? Are you sure about that?

Comment: What could this be used for?

Comment: Since you are casting this to an `Object`, you’ve lost the type information anyway, so your `int[][]` is just an array of objects (which holds an `int[]`).  You could recursively call your function with `numDimension-1` for dimensions higher than two, and clone copies into a new `Object[]` array.  Of course, why you’d do this is beyond me.

Comment: But, again, one cannot resist asking: Why?

Comment: I know this is strange, but this will be used in a game I am creating, in with you will play in random generated multi dimensional mazes.

Comment: A strange game; the only winning move is not to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
public static Object nArray(int n) {
     int[]dim = new int [n];
     Arrays.fill(dim, n);
     return Array.newInstance(int.class,dim);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using this more generic way: public static Object nArray(int... dimensionSizes) { return Array.newInstance(int.class, dimensionSizes); }

Comment: I was thinking why don't you make a one dimensional array with get and set methods that helps you find the right index? just a crude example https://pastebin.com/k0hqcu5Y

Comment: Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could return a single-dimension array with an explicit capacity and parse it as if it were a multidimensional array.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] buildMultiDimensionalArray(int dimensions, Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, dimensions * dimensions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Such many-dimension array is rarely seen in code. Maybe you could try one dimension array with the tuple(d1, d2 ...) mapped to the 1-d array index, the same power. for example, to visit the 2-nd row and 3-rd column of a[6][8], mapped to (2 * 8 + 3) 1-d array a[48]

Answer (score 0):

```
class nArray {
  int[] dims;
  int[] mults;
  int[] vals;
  nArray(int ... d) {
    int sum = 1;
    int len = d.length;
    dims = new int[len];
    mults = new int[len];
    for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--) {
      dims[i]=d[i];
      mults[i] = sum;
      sum*=d[i];
    }
    vals = new int[sum];
  }
  void set(int v, int ... d) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
      //if(d[i]>=dim[i]){throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(); / NullPointerException } ???
      index+=d[i]*mults[i];
    }
    vals[index] = v;
  }
  int get(int ... d) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
      // throw exception ?
      index+=d[i]*mults[i];
    }
    return vals[index];
  }
}
```

https://pastebin.com/k0hqcu5Y